# Randomising query results order, with paging

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0

I have a requirement to randomise a set of results from a query but still have paging support. Obviously I couldn't do a genuine random sort per hit to the REST API. I'm thinking some kind of randomisation of a seed which could then be used to re-generate the "random" order deterministically for subsequent calls. Is there an established way of doing this and if not, any recommendations?

I'm in a .NET 7 WebAPI using Entity Framework Core and would like to limit the results being returned from SQL Server to just the page size requested.

Comment: So does it need a new random sort value each time the list is requested, that then remained static for that session?

Comment: On initial page load (Vue SPA) the rest api will be hit with pageNumber=1&pageSize=10 but no search criteria. In this instance I want to randomise and return the first 10, but if the user clicks "Next Page" the rest api will be hit with pageNumber=2&pageSize=10 and I want the next 10 of the previously randomised list without re-ordering. And if possible only return 10 in each query. Once search criteria keywords are provided then the randomisation is discarded.

Comment: Doe the "random" order need to be different on different fresh calls? Or can it be duplicated? I guess the point is, you are going to have to store you randomised list somewhere, the "where" will depend on how long it needs to be kept for.

Comment: There's no session as it's a rest api, I was thinking that on the first call I could generate a seed used to determine procedural generation of the results order and I'd return that see on the response. If that seed is passed back in with subsequent calls I'd use that seed to deterministically create the same record sort order that existed on the previous call.

Comment: Right, so you'd need to store that list order against that seed on your server somewhere. You seem to know what you need, so whats your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `HASHBYTES()` function to mix-up order in a repeatable way and add your own seed value:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test ( ID INT IDENTITY );
GO
-- Insert 20 rows
INSERT #Test
DEFAULT VALUES
GO 20

-- Pick any seed value
DECLARE @SeedValue INT = 2147483647 -- Testing for Max Int Value
SELECT HASHBYTES ('SHA2_256', CAST( ID^@SeedValue AS BINARY( 4 ))) AS SortID, ID FROM #Test ORDER BY SortID, ID;
```

`ID^@SeedValue` - this is binary XOR statement. If you use simple math operators you can accidentally overflow. This avoids this.

Comment: Cool idea. Are there Linq to entities translations for this or does it need to be a sproc?